# python excel: data type issue for chinese characters

Tags: python

This is my first question in this forum. i'm a beginner in python.

Question: I am trying to retrieve a DB2 (IBM I) data from a table and write into excel sheet(.xls). To get the data, i am using pyodbc and to write into excel, xlwt module is used.
Col4 holds chinese character. i know that the col4 CCSID is 935 and pyodbc retrieves data as it is from DB but when i write this value into excel sheet, it throws following error message.Below is the data from dset1 if i print it. how do write this into excel without any issue?

0 (Decimal('6331840'), 'RUBO', '587 ', '\x0e\xa3\x1a\x1a\x1a', Decimal('175'), Decimal('3716'))
1 (Decimal('6331841'), 'RUBO', '587 ', '\x0e\xa3\x1a\x1a\x1a', Decimal('24'), Decimal('340'))
2 (Decimal('6331842'), 'RUBO', '587 ', '\x0e\xa3\x1a\x1a\x1a', Decimal('100'), Decimal('1821'))

```
File "C:\Python27\Tools\john\EOD_CMR report.py", line 82, in <module>
    sh.write(n, i, val)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 259, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'pyodbc.Row'>


import pyodbc
import os
import sys, traceback
import xlwt

#initiate excel
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sh = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
#get today date YYYYMMDD
now = datetime.datetime.now() # get today's date
today = str(now.year) + str(now.month).zfill(2) + str(now.day).zfill(2)
#SQL statement
sql1 = """SELECT col1, col2, col3, trim(col4)FROM lib.file WHERE date = %s""" % today

con_string = "Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=veet;Database=veet;UID=" + user_id + ";pwd=" + password + ";SSL=YES;unicode_results=True"

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cur = cnxn.cursor()
# get the data
dset1 = cur.execute(sql1).fetchall()
cur.close()

# to write column name
x = ['Packlist', 'Carrier', 'Hub', 'City', 'Carton amount', 'DU']
n = 0
for i, hdr in enumerate(x):
        sh.write(n,i,hdr)
for i, val in enumerate(dset1):
        n+=1
        sh.write(n, i, val)
name = today + 'xls'
book.save(name)
```

Update on the issue:
I solved the issue finally. below is the hidden bug..
1. 1st trick is to encode retrieved data using Microsoft unicode value = CCSID 1386 in ODBC driver itself..

```
con_string = "Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=veet;Database=veet;UID=" + user_id + ";pwd=" + password + ";SSL=YES;unicode_results=True;CCSID=1386"
```

reference: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc%2Ffr22370_.htm

1. 2nd is to decode this value using xlwt during workbook initiation like below.

   book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="gb2312")

Reference: http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Thanks all for giving me some directions on this

Comment: Can you eliminate Excel or ODBC from the problem? My guess is that the problem is encoding-based, but it's hard to tell which part has issues here, only that they don't match. Also, what is the type of the "unexpected data type"?

Comment: Do you have any ability to change the encoding of the characters?  CCSID 935 is not one of the encodings covered by the standard Python library (http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) so you'd have to find or write a custom codec for it.  Ultimately, `xlwt` needs input either in Unicode objects or bytestrings that are encoded in its declared encoding (which it will use to decode them, using Python's standard selection), so your basic path should be to `decode` the col4 value from a bytestring into a Unicode object before writing it.

Comment: Also, `dset` is going to be a list of rows, where each row is a tuple-like object.  You can't directly write them with xlwt, which is probably why you're getting an exception.  You need a nested for loop - `for rownum, row in enumerate(dset1): for colnum, val in enumerate(row): sh.write(rownum, colnum, val)`.  That's independent of your encoding difficulties (which are going to be a real problem) but still important.

Comment: One more amendment - `rownum` in the nested for loop needs to start at 1, not 0, since you're writing headers to row 0.  `sh.write(rownum + 1` would do it, or just track it directly and increment in each for loop as you were trying to do with `n`.

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt, the unexpected data type strings and it's CCSID is 935 in DB2

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper, i know that is the way i should go but what is the unicode that i should use for decode? i tried lots of unicode but failed to write into excel with same error message.

Comment: Python's built in libraries can't decode CCSID 935.  You'll have to find a third-party codec or write something that can.  It's not a simple problem.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper,  Thanks, you are right about logic that we have to do. finally got the solution, updated solution above.